# maxInboundMessageSize when trying to save a protobuf object to firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using gRPC protobuf for my project and in the auth sub-module I have this piece of code:

```
    @Override
    public void signUp(SignUpRequest request, StreamObserver<SignUpResponse> response) {
        String email = request.getEmail();
        String password = request.getPassword();
        User user;
        long now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest()
                .setEmail(request.getEmail())
                .setPassword(request.getPassword())
                .setEmailVerified(true);
        UserRecord userRecord;
        try {
            userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserAsync(createRequest).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.onError(Status.INTERNAL.withDescription("User creation interrupted").asRuntimeException());
            return;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.onError(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.withDescription("Invalid email or password").asRuntimeException());
            return;
        }


        user = User.newBuilder()
                .setEmail(request.getEmail())
                .setCreatedAt(now)
                .setUpdatedAt(now)
                .build();
        log.info("user record"+userRecord.toString());


        try {
            String jsonString = JsonFormat.printer().print(user);
            Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
            DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("users").document();
            userRef.set(jsonString);
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info(user.toString());


        SignUpResponse signUpResponse = SignUpResponse.newBuilder()
                .setUser(user)
                .setResponseTime(now)
                .setResponseStatus(200)
                .build();

        response.onNext(signUpResponse);
        response.onCompleted();
    }
```

As you can see I am using firebase to authenticate and trying to save the user in users collection in firestore. But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: maxInboundMessageSize
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize(NettyChannelBuilder.java:531)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize(NettyChannelBuilder.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:370)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:105)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:83)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:236)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:230)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:132)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:127)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:560)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:358)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:64)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:540)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:55)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:32)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient$FirestoreInstances.lambda$get$0(FirestoreClient.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Collections.java:2760)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient$FirestoreInstances.get(FirestoreClient.java:150)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getInstance(FirestoreClient.java:121)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:98)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:83)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:68)
    at server.AuthServiceImpl.signUp(AuthServiceImpl.java:83)
    at root.protos.auth.AuthServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(AuthServiceGrpc.java:277)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.util.TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor$1.onHalfClose(TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor.java:74)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:335)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
```

In the parent pom I have:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf-java.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

where `<grpc.version>1.41.0</grpc.version>` and
`<protobuf-java.version>3.19.0</protobuf-java.version>`

Now I am not sure about the issue. Is it because firestore doesn't support proto objects or something else? And what can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running into classloader hell.

The field `maxInboundMessageSize` was local to the class `NettyChannelBuilder`, but as of 1.51.x that field was moved to the parent class `AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder`.  Probably the version of firestore you are using is pulling in a newer version of gRPC and one version is creating the object while the other version is being used for the class method logic.

I would recommend upgrading your gRPC version to 1.53.0.

Comment: can you explain why I am getting this error: `Found conflicting getters for name getDefaultInstanceForType on class root.protos.auth.User` please?